# HAProxy with Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, haproxy

I have frontend/backend application I want to scale so I am using Docker Swarm. I understand how ingress routing mesh of docker swarm mode works, but I am confused about HAProxy coming into the picture. I would like for access point to be one host, meaning you can't access the application from other hosts. Should I turn off docker swarm loadbalancer? If so, how should I do that? Can I place loadbalancer in docker swarm, on one host (ie. manager)? If both ingress network and HAProxy were working together, wouldn't that defeating the point of having a HAProxy?